# What does the * operator do outside of a function [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.9

I was looking at a youtube tutorial and saw someone use this syntax (I don't remember the name of the video or who made it because it was weeks ago, but, it's something like this):

```
bar(*variable)
```

What I've observed while messing around with the `*` operator.

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
foo(*nums) # Assuming foo has only one argument, throws an error saying it expects 1 argument, not 3.
```

So if I have a `foo` function with 3 arguments `foo(a, b, c)` then passing in `foo(*nums)` will work just fine. Another example is the `asyncio.gather()` function with has an argument called `*aws` which lets me do this:

```
asyncio.gather(*coros)
```

Its quite handy since I can't pass in a list of coroutine objects (my knowledge on asyncio is rusty, so don't mind the incorrect terms, but, feel free to correct me). So that makes it very useful.
I have tried at guess what it does. From messing around like this:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
print(*nums)
# 1, 2, 3
```

It seems to just do "quick unpacking"?
I can also do

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
a, *b = nums # lets me store the rest of the values in b
print(a) # 1
print(b) # [2, 3]
```

From what I can see it just allows for quick unpacking. And to pass in lists as function arguments in an unconventional way. And I've also not seen the `*` operator used a lot. So I'm very curious as to what it really does, and it's actual application.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question, this is specifically about the use "outside function", the question linked as duplicate is purely about "inside function call".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Python documentation covers the use of the `*` operator both inside and outside of functions. Maybe the OP should start [here](https://docs.python.org/3/genindex-Symbols.html), look at all the docs related to `*`, and come back if something was unclear.